# Anyone know if there is an equivalent in Web forms to using @model mymodel in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, webforms

So in MVC you can go something like:

C#:

```
public ActionResult Index() 
{
    var viewModel = new MyViewModel();
    return View(viewModel) ;
}
```

View:

```
@model ViewModels.MyViewModel;

Do stuff with model here...
```

Is there an equivalent if being able to do this in Web Forms? My problem is that I've been developing using MVC for the past few years, and I've been sent on a course to learn web forms for some stupid reason, and I'm trying to use them as much like MVC as I can.

Comment: There is no `@model` equivalent in webforms, but you can use MVP (Model-View-Presenter) design pattern instead. The presenter replaces controller which bound to model classes using interfaces and event handlers.